# Document count limit under folders

Tags: 2013, document-library, limitations

We are trying to figure out what the library file count restriction is for items under a folder.

We can see here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ListLibrary

Documents :: 30,000,000 per library >> You can create very large document libraries by nesting folders, or using standard views and site hierarchy. This value may vary depending on how documents and folders are organized, and by the type and size of documents stored.

Does that mean there is a file count limit of some sort under folders for a library?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR - Stay under 5,000 items for the entire library to get 100% of functionality

In addition to the 30 million documents per library you also need to be aware of the limit of 5,000 items per "view".

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787(v=office.15).aspx#ListLibrary

This particular limit can be changed in on-premise but in SharePoint Online it cannot. This means that Microsoft does not recommend having more than 5,000 folders or documents within a single folder. You can continue to nest folders but any single folder should not have more than 5,000 direct children (items or folders).

That being said... you will find there are limitations putting more than 5,000 documents into a single library no matter how efficient your foldering structure. This is because certain operations will apply to all items below a certain level and those operations (if they affect more than 5,000 items) will be throttled.

In my experience this includes:

- Adding a indexed property to the library that contains more than 5,000
- Changing permissions on t he library and or folder that contains more than 5,000

Answer (score 0):

A document Library can hold more than  30,000,000 denouements but catch is MSFT support upto 30,000,000 and if you exceed you will be out of support. That's mean MSFT will tell you delete the documents stay in limit.

So, 30 Million is upper limit, whatever folder structure you have and number of folder you have....all together should not exceed 30 Million.